# Hibernate JPA not creating script for database schema

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have configured the `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target` property to generate a script into a file name. But it is surely not being created, as I searched my entire home directory (on MacOS) for the file using the `find` command and it is not being found.

I have tried `foo.sql`, `./foo.sql` and `/tmp/foo.sql` and cannot find it anywhere in my home directory or `/tmp`

The database tables are indeed being created and I don't see any errors in the output.

Here is my full simple code:

`persistence.xml`

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="foo">
        <class>Foo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql:///main" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="main" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="big1704cloudmain" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="foo" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="validate" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="foo.sql" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

`Main.kt`

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.Id
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence

@Entity
data class Foo (@Id val n: Int)

fun main() {
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foo")
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "latest.release"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:latest.release")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:latest.release")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(18))
    }
}
```

`Run Output`

```
3:15:36 PM: Executing 'run'...

> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :run
Hello World!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 737ms
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: foo]
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.2.Final
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:postgresql:///main]
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=main}
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH035001: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, version: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$DialectResolutionInfoImpl@72ade7e3
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard resolveConstructor
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: Foo (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
May 13, 2023 3:15:36 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7ff35a3f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
3:15:36 PM: Execution finished 'run'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Generate Database Schema with Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema), you need to include this:

```
 spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
```

in the persistence unit properties.

If you still can't find the generated script after adding and using the above, try making the `create-target` pathname an absolute pathname.