# how generate update script from entity model in hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-6.x

I want to generate update script(ddl alter/create statement) from my hibernate models.
in hibernate 4.x there is a method named

```
generateSchemaUpdateScriptList
```

in class Configuration, but I do not know is there any alternative way for this purpose in hibernate 6 ?

I searched for it but I do not find any thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241881/175554 may help, could not find direct replace for generateSchemaUpdateScriptList but update happens [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/75f3ad96514c7bf7354d7462aba67ad718e9a4cd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java#L436) someone may write some code to collect those update scripts.